# How to wrap java events with javascript interface on android

Tags: javascript, java, android, myo

I am trying to wrap java events of Myo armband Android SDK using javascript interface on android so that I will be able to implement the event in javascript and build my app with javascript afterwards.

```
private DeviceListener deviceListener = new AbstractDeviceListener() {
@Override
    public void onAttach(Myo myo, long timestamp) {
        super.onAttach(myo, timestamp);
    }
};
```

I was able to create `JavascriptInterface` for the normal methods but I could not figure out how to do that for events. My javascript or event knowledge might be lacking so if you could give me a simple example or point me some reading I would appreciate it.